# Dictionary on powerpoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I want to add dictionary on powerpoint 2013.I searched and found "adding custom.dic files" for a solution but it is too pointless to create word files which includes all english words with their meaining in my native language.
Is there any ready to use way to do that ? 
I want to have a dictionary like in mozilla firefox dictionary add-on (when you point a word with the mouse cursor,a pop-up box appears and shows the selected word with their meaning in your language like english to french translation)
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality already exists (at least in PowerPoint 2010). Position your cursor in the middle of a word (or select it) and right click. `Translate` is one of the options. The following shows what I got when doing so while the curoosr is positioned in `Walls`:

[image]